# PHP: How to use string variable as table in sql query (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, pdo

I would like to make a general function to select last inserted id's of different tables.

I already tried multiple things, this might be the best effort (in db.inc.php);

```
<?php
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'modlar' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASS', 'password' );

function verbinden(){
  $verbinding = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';DB_NAME=' . DB_NAME;
  $db = null;

  try{
    return new PDO( $verbinding, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
  }catch( PDOException $e ){
    return NULL;
  }
}

function loopdoor( $naam, $ding){
  $regels = '';
  if( is_array($ding) || is_object($ding)):
    $wat = (is_array($ding)? 'array' : 'object');
    $regels .= '<strong>'.$naam.'['.$wat.']</strong><ul>';
    foreach( $ding as $k => $v):
      $regels .= loopdoor( $k, $v);
    endforeach;
    $regels .= '</ul>';
  else:
    $regels .= '<li><strong>'.$naam.'</strong> => '.$ding.'</li>';
  endif;
  return $regels;
}

function last_id( &$db , $table, $column){
  if( is_null( $db ) ) return array();

  $sql = "
    SELECT
      max(modlar.table.column)
    FROM
      modlar.table";

  $vraag = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $vraag->bindValue( ':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $vraag->bindValue( ':column', $column, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $vraag->execute();
  return $vraag->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}
```

Where modlar is my database. And my variables (in db.php);

```
<?php
require_once 'db.inc.php';

// Verbinden met database
$db = verbinden();
if( is_null($db))
  die('<h1>Error</h1>');

echo 'done';

$table = 'time';
$column = 'time_id';
$last = last_id($db, $table, $column);
echo '<ul>'.loopdoor('all data', $last).'</ul>';
?>
```

But I dont get any data on my screen (and no error). However, when I add the variables directly to the code, I'll get the last id of that table. So like;

```
  $sql = "
    SELECT
      max(modlar.time.time_id)
    FROM
      modlar.time";
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: You bind value but there're no placeholders in your query. Why do you bind then?

Comment: You cannot bind table or column names. If you want to use variable table and column names, validate them beforehand. And you are not actually binding anything since you're not defining them in your query.

Comment: *"I dont get any data on my screen (and no error)"* ... looks like there are errors to me, you're just not displaying them.

Comment: @aynber how can I validate them beforehand?

Comment: and to all, @CD001, why am I not binding the variables? should i use :table, and :column instead?

Comment: You can create an array of approved table names and column names, and make sure that it exists.